# I'm using the Slugalicious gem. How do I create slugs for existing data in my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs

I'm using the slugalicous gem in my rails app.  I set it up so my app creates new slugs when I create new blog posts, but it doesn't create slugs for all the existing blog posts in my database.  How do I create slugs for existing blog posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `.save` on each record should trigger slug creation.  Assuming your model is called `Post`:

```
Post.find_each {|post| post.save}
```